# Can we switch the "StackExchange" button on the menu bar with a Sports SE button?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

On the very top left corner of the website we have the stack exchange logo, which looks like this:

[image: StackExchangeLogo]

Clicking on it gives you a pop up asking if you want to visit the stack exchange home page. Under the menu bar we have a horizontal header that says "Sports"/"Sports Meta" with nothing else on it. Clicking on only the text takes you to the homepage of the Sports SE/its meta respectively. I was wondering if we have the ability to remove the SE logo on the top and replace it with the Sports/Sports Meta row. Or is this a restriction of being a beta site? This is something I've wondered for many years now and don't remember ever asking about it.

I've always found the header awkward and a waste of real estate. Removing it allows 1 more question on the homepage and more text on the questions, which provides marginal efficiency having more info on the screen. Also do we really need an SE button in the site? I'd think the SE system wants it there, not Sports SE itself. I guess I'm too used to clicking the top left button to get back to the homepage on stackoverflow without even reading it, that I hit the top left button on Sports SE too, almost every time I visit the site and have a mental facepalm realizing I've done it yet another time years into using it.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 2):

No, we cannot do this.

A large amount of the design and infrastructure is baked into the Stack Exchange network as a whole, and is not customisable.

If we sent this request onward to the Community Management team, they would reply that we already have such a link (the title you mention) as well as the drop-down menu (in the top right corner) to get to either the main or meta site.

Comment: That's sad that it would get refused right off the bat

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Catija's post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319274/responsive-design-themes-what-can-sites-customize-and-how-can-they-get-changes) to see an example of some of the things that sites *can* customize.

However, we have not yet had our "site design" phase yet, and likely won't for a long time (we're a tiny site, with very little traffic, so we get to be very low on the priority list unfortunately).  That's likely required first; and unfortunately design takes a lot of resources, so even if we did get to that phase it would be months before anything changed.

When we do reach that point, we'll get a bunch of meta posts related to it.

Comment: when do sites usually reach the site design phase?

Comment: It used to be "graduation", which required something like 10 questions/day and a certain level of viewers and such.  I use that only to show how far we are from that; it's likely no longer a requirement.  Some sites, like Parenting, have been around basically from the beginning and never got to that size - and so still haven't had their site design.  We'd almost certainly be after Parenting, so that might be an indicator - when they get it, we will probably be not too long after.  But I'm not sure how many resources are being put into design at this point.

Comment: Part of why they rolled out "design independent graduation" (which we've reached) was because of this, I think - it allowed them to spend less resources on site design.